# How to add "Settings" button to Exoplayer's navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I want to use Exoplayer. So i just simply want to add something like "Settings" button in this default navigation player. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add setting button in exoplayer then you can add like this. It will display as in image[image: Preview of Exoplayer]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity.DemoActivity">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/normal_video_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />
</LinearLayout>
```